# Expandable PDF textbox in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is there no way to make a fillable PDF that will dynamically expand as the user inputs text? After hours of searching only 1 solution keeps popping up and that is Adobe Livecycle which now seems to be impossible to get.

Is it possible to make the text box dynamic and expandable in indesign instead? Is there any other way possible to do this like html, css, javascript but saved as a pdf file?

Comment: The only way I could think to do this would be to have javascript tied to the multi-line text area in the PDF. Then for each key up, check the overflow and adjust. I have *no clue* if this would effectively work or merely bog down the text area beyond usability. Why do you need it to "expand"?? A multi-line text area will scroll to allow the user to see any overflow and auto-expanding typically breaks a layout.

Comment: that would work but if they printed the form it would get cut off. They need to be able to fill in the form and print it. So the tables height needs to expand if they write alot. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: In general, people will write as much as the field will hold. You could always add an additional page with a large multi-line text area for additional comments. Kind of a "use the back if you need more space" type of thing. Just throwing out ideas though. No clue if they'll work for your particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

PDF does not support this kind of field.

I have developed some kind of kludgy solution which allows the field to grow (but not to shrink), but that can not be pre-defined in InDesign.

Adobe's official solution would be using XFA (which means the LiveCycle Designer for the forms design). But that would then require any user of your forms to view it with an Adobe product (Acrobat (Reader) ), and it would not work on devices (if that matters).